# Upload file to node.js server from Android using HTTPURLConnection

Tags: javascript, android, node.js

If someone can help guide me on what exactly I am doing wrong.. A little stumped on this one as I've used Postman Client to do a get request to my node.js server and am able to get to it perfectly fine.

```
04-28 01:21:03.983 5362-5486/xyz.hexene.localvpn I/uploadFile: HTTP Response is : Not Found: 404
04-28 01:21:03.983 5362-5486/xyz.hexene.localvpn E/404 ERROR: Not Found
```

Here is my android code:

```
   public void uploadFile() {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            DataOutputStream dos = null;
            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary = "*****";
            int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
            byte[] buffer;
            int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
            File sourceFile = new File(AccountInfo.getContext().getFilesDir() + "/" + fileName);

            if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
                Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :" + AccountInfo.getContext().getFilesDir() + "/" + fileName);
            } else {
                try {

                    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                    URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.66:3000/upload");
                    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                    //conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                    conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                    //  conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                    conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);


                    dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());


                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

                    //Adding Parameter name

                    String name = "amir";
                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"name\"" + lineEnd);
                    //dos.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" + lineEnd);
                    //dos.writeBytes("Content-Length: " + name.length() + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(name); // mobile_no is String variable
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

                    //Adding Parameter phone
                    String phone = "9956565656";
                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"phone\"" + lineEnd);
                    //dos.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" + lineEnd);
                    //dos.writeBytes("Content-Length: " + name.length() + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(phone); // mobile_no is String variable
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);


                    //Json_Encoder encode=new Json_Encoder();
                    //call to encode method and assigning response data to variable 'data'
                    //String data=encode.encod_to_json();
                    //response of encoded data
                    //System.out.println(data);


                    //Adding Parameter filepath

                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                    String filepath = "http://192.168.1.110/echo/uploads" + fileName;

                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"filepath\"" + lineEnd);
                    //dos.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" + lineEnd);
                    //dos.writeBytes("Content-Length: " + name.length() + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(filepath); // mobile_no is String variable
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);


                    //Adding Parameter media file(audio,video and image)

                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\"" + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    // create a buffer of maximum size
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                    // read file and write it into form...
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                    while (bytesRead > 0) {
                        dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    }

                    // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);


                    serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                    String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();


                    Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                    if (serverResponseCode == 200) {

                        Log.e("PASSED", "IT WORKS!!! YESS");
                    } else {
                            Log.e("404 ERROR", conn.getResponseMessage());
                    }

                    // close the streams //
                    fileInputStream.close();
                    dos.flush();
                    dos.close();

                } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();


                    Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
                } catch (final Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                    Log.e("Upload file Exception",
                            "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
                }
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}
```

And below is my node.js server: (Sorry I know it isn't impressive i'm still learning node.js)

```
1 var express = require('express')
  2 var app = express()
  3 var multer  = require('multer')
  4 var upload = multer()
  5 
  6 app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  7   res.send('Hello World! (' + Date.now() + ")");
  8 });
  9 
 10 var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
 11   console.log("Express server is started. (port: 3000)");
 12 });
 13 
 14 app.get('/upload', upload.array(), function(req,res){
 15   //console.log(req); //form fields
 16   console.log(res.files); //form files
 17 
 18 
 19   res.send("You got to the upload");
 20 });
```

I had conn.setDoOutput(true) uncommented before and still the same error. My Node.js server isn't up and running now as I'm just testing this locally so if you try to ping the node.js server it won't show that is currently up.

Comment: consider using OKHTTP client. HttpUrlConnection is old and buggy.